# How is this site forcing page reloads with JavaScript disabled?

Tags: javascript

I have disabled JavaScript using the Firefox extension uMatrix and yet some websites are still able to force page reloads at an interval referenced by a script on that page. How is this possible please, and can I prevent it?

For example, `https://www.drudgereport.com/` contains the following script tag meant to reload the page every 105 seconds:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
var img = new Image(), url = "/204.png", container = document.getElementById("div-204");
img.onload = function () { container.appendChild(img); };
img.src = url;
var timer = setInterval("__drudge__321__autoRefresh()", 1000 * 35 * 3);
function __drudge__321__autoRefresh(){self.location.reload(true);}
(function () {
    var __oldClearInterval = clearInterval;

    clearInterval = function (arg) {
        if(arg == timer) {
                console.log("clearInterval of TIMER intercepted! (" + arg + ")");
        }
        else {
                __oldClearInterval(arg);
        }
    }
})();
//--> 
</script>
```

With JavaScript **disabled**, the page still reloads every 105 seconds, indefinitely. My expectation is that when I disable JavaScript, scripts embedded in the page are prevented from executing.

Comment: This has nothing to do with security.

Comment: @ThoriumBR I'm happy to delete the question if it is off-topic here. I thought JavaScript was somehow being executed, and my first thought was that it was a security problem. The accepted answer explains it now.

Comment: Unwanted reloads is one of the most annoying "feature" of the Web, together with video auto-start. Although understanding the way they work is important for security, the fact they exist is not in itself a security issue, but a usability issue. How to disable JS is both a usability issue (some JS features can be pretty annoying) and a security issue.

Comment: Look into HTML meta refresh.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The page refreshes periodically because of this tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="105">
```

That asks the browser to refresh, without needing JavaScript.

Comment: ... and the page could achieve that goal even without adding that tag to its content by using the corresponding http-header directly